# When does Service Fabric update the list of available service partition endpoints?

Tags: c#, service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric

I am working on a service (let's call it ServiceA) that exposes an endpoint.  The service will be hosted in Service Fabric and will run on (for example) three of five available nodes.  Another service (ServiceB) needs to be able to contact all three running instances of ServiceA.  In order to do that, I am using the ServicePartitionResolver from ServiceB to find all of the endpoints exposed by the (single) ServiceA service partition.  This works just fine until I kill one of the nodes on which ServiceA is running.  I would expect that another instance of ServiceA is created on one of the other nodes and the list of endpoints returned by ServicePartitionResolver.Resolve is updated to reflect the change.  This doesn't seem to happen, though.  In fact even if I query the REST API directly (using Postman to hit: http://[cluster-ip]:19080/Services/ApplicationA~ServiceA/$/ResolvePartition?api-version=6.0) I continue to see a 'stale' result.  I have also tried using FabricClient rather than ServicePartitionResolver to check that it's not a locally cached result that I am seeing.

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Having done a bit more experimentation, I think I know what is going on.  Service Fabric does do what I expected it to but in my case the cluster I am using for testing is not big enough.  I think that when I remove one of three nodes, the naming service can't operate effectively any more and so the results are not consistent.  If I use a four node cluster and remove one, I get the result I am expecting.